# ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module "./.../.module.ngfactory"

Tags: node.js, angularfire2, webpack-dev-server, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I followed the steps of Server-side Rendering with Universal published in the angularfire2 documentation:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/server-side-rendering.md

I achieved to compile the whole application without errors but when I was running the application I got the following error:

`ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module "./views/sessions/sessions.module.ngfactory". Error: Cannot find module "./views/sessions/sessions.module.ngfactory". at eval (webpack:///./src_lazy_namespace_object?:5:11) at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:387:26) at Object.onInvoke (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:4122:33) at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:386:32) at Zone.run (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:137:43) at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:871:34) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:420:31) at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:4113:33) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:419:36) at Zone.runTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:187:47) at resolvePromise (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:813:31) at resolvePromise (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:770:17) at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:872:17) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:420:31) at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:4113:33) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:419:36) at Zone.runTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:187:47) at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:594:35) at ZoneTask.invokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:499:21) at Server.ZoneTask.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:484:48) rejection: { Error: Cannot find module "./views/sessions/sessions.module.ngfactory". at eval (webpack:///./src_lazy_namespace_object?:5:11) at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:387:26) at Object.onInvoke (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:4122:33) at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:386:32) at Zone.run (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:137:43) at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:871:34) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:420:31) at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:4113:33) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:419:36) at Zone.runTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:187:47) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }, promise: ZoneAwarePromise { __zone_symbol__state: 0, __zone_symbol__value: { Error: Cannot find module "./views/sessions/sessions.module.ngfactory". at eval (webpack:///./src_lazy_namespace_object?:5:11) at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:387:26) at Object.onInvoke (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:4122:33) at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:386:32) at Zone.run (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:137:43) at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:871:34) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:420:31) at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:4113:33) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:419:36) at Zone.runTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:187:47) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } }, zone: Zone { _properties: { isAngularZone: true }, _parent: Zone { _properties: {}, _parent: null, _name: '', _zoneDelegate: [Object] }, _name: 'angular', _zoneDelegate: ZoneDelegate { _taskCounts: [Object], zone: [Circular], _parentDelegate: [Object], _forkZS: null, _forkDlgt: null, _forkCurrZone: [Object], _interceptZS: null, _interceptDlgt: null, _interceptCurrZone: [Object], _invokeZS: [Object], _invokeDlgt: [Object], _invokeCurrZone: [Circular], _handleErrorZS: [Object], _handleErrorDlgt: [Object], _handleErrorCurrZone: [Circular], _scheduleTaskZS: [Object], _scheduleTaskDlgt: [Object], _scheduleTaskCurrZone: [Circular], _invokeTaskZS: [Object], _invokeTaskDlgt: [Object], _invokeTaskCurrZone: [Circular], _cancelTaskZS: [Object], _cancelTaskDlgt: [Object], _cancelTaskCurrZone: [Circular], _hasTaskZS: [Object], _hasTaskDlgt: [Object], _hasTaskDlgtOwner: [Circular], _hasTaskCurrZone: [Circular] } }, task: ZoneTask { _zone: Zone { _properties: [Object], _parent: [Object], _name: 'angular', _zoneDelegate: [Object] }, runCount: 0, _zoneDelegates: null, _state: 'notScheduled', type: 'microTask', source: 'Promise.then', data: ZoneAwarePromise { __zone_symbol__state: 0, __zone_symbol__value: [Object] }, scheduleFn: undefined, cancelFn: null, callback: [Function], invoke: [Function] } }`

I was checking and the error is in the file `webpack.server.config.js`
With the WebPack plugIn `new Webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin`
It causes conflict with the aot lazy load.

**Steps to set up and reproduce**

I created a repository for you so that you can reproduce this error that I commented to you before:
https://github.com/IngAjVillalon/Angular-Universal-6-Server-Side-Render
You can execute:

```
npm install
```

later

```
npm run build: ssr && npm run serve: ssr.
```

and the application will run fine, but when using the application the error appears.

**Can you help me, please, by telling us what other alternatives we have to run the aot lazy load with Server-side Rendering with Universal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lazy loading you'll need to pass your LAZY_MODULE_MAP into the render factory's providers. Check out what AngularFire2've done in the new SSR docs up for review in [Getting started with Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/dfaaac880d2829a893d471a2ee3811b79fcfaff3/docs/universal/getting-started.md):

They also have a project I'm working on here which implements SSR with AOT & lazy modules: [jamesdaniels/AngularFireDocs](https://github.com/jamesdaniels/AngularFireDocs)

Comment: Hi Sacscloud, welcome to SO. Please be aware that [link only answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) are subject to deletion. The ideal answer would supplement those links with a summary of their core content, in case the links disappear it won't completely invalidate your answer. Thanks for contributing to SO!

Comment: Hi @MatthewLDaniel, thank you very much for the comment. Now I understand more.